# Returning None after conditional

Tags: python

Trying to return the math.floor of k, which is 2

```
import numpy as np
import math
j = 1

def k(j):
    k = j + 1.2 
    return k       # 2.2

def foo2():
    num = k(j)
    floor = math.floor(num)
    threshold = 5.1
    a = 22.5094
    i = np.arange(threshold, 50)
    if a in i:
        return floor 
print(foo2())
```

It worked without conditional

```
import math
j = 1

def k(j):
    k = j + 1.2
    return k        #2.2

def foo2():
    num = k(j)
    b = math.floor(num)
    return b

print(foo2())
```

If you spot where I made a wrong assumption, do share please.

Comment: The default return value of a Python function is `None`, as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) under `None`. Thus, if your conditional `a in i` evaluates `False`, you will get a `None` return value.

Comment: `foo2` returns floor if `a in i`. What do you think it returns if `a in i` is false?

Comment: Try to print `np.arange(threshold, 50)`, none of those values will be equal to `a` precisely. And without it, the `in` condition will be False

Comment: No. You should never compre two floating point numbers with `==` or `in` (which comes down to `==` anyway). [Read this](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)

Comment: think I'll go the truncation way, not sure about implementing the others. https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-decimal/

Answer (score 0):

Try add line: `print(a, i)`
after: `i = np.arange(threshold, 50)`

You will see that a doesn't belong to i, and becouse of this if that is in the next line will not execute return function, becouse as we saw earlier there is no any value in list i that is equal to value of a.
And if return in function isn't executed then function will return None.